# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index on dynamically generated Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm creating dynamic checkbox and  textbox Control on page Load and i want to get the values of control on button click but we are not able to find out

here is my Dynamic control Code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    var Count = dt.Rows.Count;
    if (Count > 0)
    {


        TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
        TableHeaderCell cellheader = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell thcode = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell thcReason = new TableHeaderCell();
        thc.Text = "Select";
        thc.CssClass = "pd";
        thcode.Text = "Description";
        thcode.CssClass = "pdlbl";
        thcReason.Text = "Reason";
        thcReason.CssClass = "thcReason";
        thr.Cells.Add(thc);
        thr.Cells.Add(thcode);
        thr.Cells.Add(thcReason);
        tbl.Rows.Add(thr);

        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            Label lbl = new Label();
            TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
            txtBox.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
            txtBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            chk.ID = "chk" + i.ToString();
            lbl.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString();
            lbl.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();
            tc.Controls.Add(chk);
            tc.Width = new Unit("5px");
            tc.CssClass = "chkcntrl";
            tc1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            tc1.Width = new Unit("75%");
            tc2.Controls.Add(txtBox);
            tc2.Width = new Unit("20%");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
        }

        tbl.EnableViewState = true;
        ViewState["tbl"] = true;
    }
```

after create the control i want to find out the values

my code are below

```
foreach (TableRow tr in tbl.Controls)
    {
        string str_Confirmed = string.Empty;
        string str_Description = string.Empty;
        string str_Reason = string.Empty;
        foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Controls)
        {

            if (tc.Controls[0] is CheckBox)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)tc.Controls[0]).Checked == true)
                {
                    str_Confirmed = "Y";
                }
                else
                {
                    str_Confirmed = "N";
                }
            }
            if (tc.Controls[1] is Label)
            {
                string txt = string.Empty;
                str_Description = ((Label)tc.Controls[1]).Text;
            }
            if (tc.Controls[2] is TextBox)
            {

                str_Reason = ((TextBox)tc.Controls[2]).Text;
                //Response.Write(((TextBox)tc.Controls[0]).Text);
            }
```

}

but when i will execute this code we are getting the `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index` please any one can tell me where am wrong

Comment: Why don't you use a web databound control like `GridView`?

Comment: not a specific for that just we are working on that many time so am using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different table cells for each control you are adding.

tc has the checkbox control 
tc1 has the label control

EDIT: A few other changes were needed to your code.

1. You were iterating through, tbl.Controls not tbl.Rows
2. You were iterating through tr.Controls not tr.Cells
3. The first table row you add is the header information that has no
   controls so added check that controls.count() is greater than 0

Hope this helps

```
foreach (TableRow tr in tbl.Rows)
        {
            string str_Confirmed = string.Empty;
            string str_Description = string.Empty;
            string str_Reason = string.Empty;
            foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
            {
                if (tc.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (tc.Controls[0] is CheckBox)
                    {
                        if (((CheckBox)tc.Controls[0]).Checked == true)
                        {
                            str_Confirmed = "Y";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str_Confirmed = "N";
                        }
                    }
                    else if (tc.Controls[0] is Label)
                    {
                        string txt = string.Empty;
                        str_Description = ((Label)tc.Controls[1]).Text;
                    }
                    else if (tc.Controls[0] is TextBox)
                    {

                        str_Reason = ((TextBox)tc.Controls[2]).Text;
                        //Response.Write(((TextBox)tc.Controls[0]).Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the difference between your code and my code\

Comment: the index of the controls in if statements are all tc.controls[0]

Comment: but it throw the error on this line :-  if (tc.Controls[0] is CheckBox)